# Find \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}A_n and \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}A_n

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification

Noy sure my understanding is right here. The $\limsup = A \cup B, \; \liminf=A\cap B$ because given any $n$, $A \cup B$ exists. Not sure how to explain $\liminf$ exactly.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, $\liminf=A\cap B$, I forgot to type it in, I just wonder why is it so.

Comment: It depends on what properties you know of liminf and limsup. One property is that the liminf has another way to be described: $$\liminf A_n = \{ x \in \Omega : \mathrm{eventually } \  x \in A_n \}$$ while $$\limsup A_n = \{ x \in \Omega : \mathrm{infinitely \ often \ } \  x \in A_n \}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Look for the definitions of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ for sets. Then study the following sets
$$
\bigcap_{n\ge m}A_n,\quad 
\bigcup_{n\ge m}A_n, \quad
\bigcup_{m\ge 1}\bigcap_{n\ge m}A_n,\quad 
\bigcap_{m\ge 1}\bigcup_{n\ge m}A_n
$$